# How Can I Access a VB.net Timer in ThisAddIn From a Different Class

Tags: vb.net, vsto

I have set up a timer in an Office addin (being developed in VB.net) that I can set going fine, using the code:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

 Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer

 Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    Me.Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer()
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 500
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True

 End Sub

 Private Sub Timer1_Elapsed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed

    Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
    MsgBox("Code Ran!")

 End Sub
```

I would like to call this timer when a user changes a setting in the addin's ribbon, but I cannot seem to access the event.  If I use the code:

```
Public Class ServerRibbon

 Public myCaller As ThisAddIn

 private sub respondToClick()

    Dim blah As System.Timers.Timer
    blah = myCaller.Timer1
    blah.Enabled = True

 end sub
```

I get an error of 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  Can anyone explain how I can set the timer going?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `myCaller` is not set to your particular instance of `ThisAddIn` (theoretically, there could be many `ThisAddIn` instances floating around your memory).

However, since you are developing an office add-in, there is in fact only a single instance of ThisAddIn. A simple workaround to get access to the timer would be to make Timer1 a shared variable:

```
Friend Shared WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer
```

This would allow you to access the timer as `ThisAddIn.Timer1`.

(Note that, *in general*, publicly accessible shared fields (aka global variables) are a bad idea. However, in your case, it might just be the simplest solution that allows you to do what you want.)

PS: You might want to read up on the difference between a *class* and an *instance of a class*.

---

*EDIT*: Since you have an event handler attached to the timer, you either

(a) need to make the event handler shared as well (`Private Shared Sub Timer1_Elapsed...`), which has the disadvantage that your event handler cannot access instance variables of ThisAddIn anymore, or

(b) Make the instance of `ThisAddIn` accessible through a separate property instead of making the field shared:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer

    Private Shared _instance As ThisAddIn
    Public ReadOnly Shared Property Instance() As ThisAddIn
        Get
            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        _instance = Me

        Me.Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer()
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 500
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
     End Sub

...

Public Class ServerRibbon
    Private Sub respondToClick()
        ThisAddIn.Instance.Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion.  The only problem now is that when I try to access the timer I get a new error message of "Events of shared WithEvents variables cannot be handled by non-shared methods."  Any idea how I solve it?

Comment: @user867358: Add the "Shared" keyword to your method definition as well: `Private Shared Sub Timer1_Elapsed...`

Comment: Hi Heinzi - it works if you don't use the instance bits!  The me's need replacing with ThisAddIn, but it doesn't recognise instance way...

Answer (score 0):

You could make the Timer itself shared, but a more elegant way would be to make a function/sub thats starts the timer a public function and call this

Comment: Thanks for the answer - only one problem; now I have public sub, but when I try to call it startTimer() doesn't work as it's not defined in this module. myCaller.startTimer() gives an error of object reference is not set to an instance of an object....

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anyone else, you can also access the instantiated ThisAddIn object via `Globals.ThisAddIn`

So,

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Public N As Integer = 42

    ...

End Class
```

and elsewhere in your project:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        Dim myint= Globals.ThisAddIn.N
    End Sub
End Class
```